# select multiple values in solr via the query array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I have Rails app with Solr field multivalues:

```
 <field name='industry_id' type='pint' indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />
```

i want to search field multivalues ​​with an array like: `fq: industry_id: [1, 2, 3]`.
After researching, I knew that if I wanted to do that, it had to be like `fq: industry_id: (1 2 3)` but in `solr_service` i define method:

```
#ids is an array
def suggest_jobs(ids)
    q = "industry_id: #{ids}"
    send_request(q)
end

def send_request(q_param)
    @solr.get 'select', params: {
      'q': q_param
    }
end
```

this is not a Syntax. How do I edit the method to match the format `fq: industry_id: (1 2 3)`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to expand the `ids` in your `suggest_jobs` to be a comma delimited list and **wrap** that value in parenthesis as shown below:

```
#ids is an array
def suggest_jobs(ids)
    ids_list = ids.join(",")
    q = "industry_id:(#{ids_list})" # industry_id:(1,2,3)
    send_request(q)
end
```

Your `send_request` method is setting the `q` parameter but in your question you mention the `fq` field. Either one should work, just make sure to adjust if needed.